# #Pentaho Open Source BI Tools

Tags: java, pentaho

I have previously worked on BI projects using MSSQL Server 2008 R2, SSAS and SSIS on a C# based ASP.net Web App. I wanted to try the same thing open source tools using Java. Could anyone please suggest me the tools?? I went through Pentaho and SpagoBI via Google Search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Open source free products
```

1. Eclipse BIRT Project
2. RapidMiner
3. SpagoBI
4. R
5. KNIME
6. TACTIC

   **Open source commercial products**
7. List item
8. Jaspersoft: Reporting, Dashboards, Data Analysis, and Data Integration
9. Palo (OLAP database): OLAP Server, Worksheet Server and ETL Server
10. Pentaho: Reporting, analysis, dashboard, data mining and workflow capabilities
11. TACTIC: Reporting, analysis, dashboard, data mining and integration, workflow capabilities

i would suggest you visit the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligence_tools)

Comment: I would use free products for initial test project. But what would I use for SSAS/SSIS/SSRS? Are they bundled up in Eclipse BIRT Project like Microsft does in MSSQL 2008 R2??

Comment: I haven't given it a try yet but these being microsoft product are not available in BIRT , if there is a special way to use them then i dont know but but I dont think they are available in BIRT

Comment: I didn't mean to use the SSAS/SSIS/SSRS.. I was just eager to know which prducts on open source give me solutions simlar to them?